# How to print out a JSON in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm new to Go, and having trouble figuring out how to print out a JSON I've created.  I'm using "encoding/json" and am getting a []byte returned.  However when I go to print this out I get:

```
cannot use json_msg (type []byte) as type string in function argument
```

After receiving this I've tried to convert the []byte array to a string or an empty interface.  However I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?  Relevant code below:

```
type Message struct {
    Id int
    Name string
}



for _, row := range rows {
    m := Message{row.Int(0), row.Str(1)}

    json_msg, err := json.Marshal(m)

    if err == nil {
        panic(err)
    }//if

            //tried below to print out a interface, didn't work either
    //var f interface{}
    //err = json.Unmarshal(json_msg, &f)

    fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, json_msg)
}//for
```

Comment: Where does the "c" of c.ResponseWriter come from?

Comment: if err == nil {
        panic(err)
    } just change condition to err != nil

Answer (score 15, accepted):

there's a handful of ways to get what you're looking for.

First, to answer your question directly, `fmt.Fprintf` if of type `func(io.Writer, string, ...interface{})`.  Since you're passing `c.ResponseWriter` into it, I assume that's something that satisfies `io.Writer`.  The second argument to `fmt.Fprintf` is a format string.  If you want to print something as a string, you use the `%s` format string, so what you would want is this:

```
fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, "%s", json_msg)
```

that answers your question directly, but let's go a little further:  is that the right way to solve the problem you're solving?  No, not really; it's a little weird to do it that way.

First off, because we know that `fmt.Fprintf` accepts `io.Writer`, we're talking about something with a method of the form `Write([]byte) (int, error)`.  You could just write that `[]byte` data to the `ResponseWriter` by calling the `Write()` method on the `ResponseWriter` directly:

```
_, err := c.ResponseWriter.Write(json_msg)
```

that's *slightly* less awkward.  It turns out, there's an even *better* way to do this:  use a `json.Encoder`.  A `json.Encoder` is a struct that *embeds* an `io.Writer`, effectively adding to any `io.Writer` struct an `Encode` method, which will encode structs to json and write them to the writer.  The difference is that what you're doing encodes the data to a byte slice in memory, and then copies that into an `io.Writer`, when you could just write it directly, like this:

```
err := json.NewEncoder(c.ResponseWriter).Encode(m)
```

and now you don't even have that intermediate `[]byte` format.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `json_msg` as the format string in a `Printf` type function, which only excepts `string` as the format string (`[]byte` and `string` are distinct types. Although you can cast them to each other). The proper way of writing a byte slice would be to specify the format string:

```
fmt.Fprintf(WRITER_OBJ, "%s", json_msg)
```

This will print the `[]byte` as it's Unicode contents. You shouldn't use varibles as the format string in Fprintf/Printf. I don't think it's a problematic as it would be in C. But it might cause issues if a "%" got in your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, string(json_msg))
```

Would be correct way to cast your `[]byte` to a `string`

Comment: It's usually considered bad memory management to cast when unnecessary.  Casting creates a copy and in this particular case, you have other great options (Write() and FPrintf("%v"))

Comment: Yes, in the case of casting bytes to a string. But his question demonstrated some ignorance as to how to cast correctly in general. I was attempting to address that.

Comment: Format string is missing in that call.